# How do you enable Territories in Salesforce

Tags: territory-management

How do you set up Sales Territories in Salesforce,in previous versions there was an option called "Manage Territories" under Administration Setup I no longer see this in the Administer section. Were can I find this or enable this?

Comment: You will need to first contact SFDC support  to get it enabled for your instance .

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps required before you can enable Territory Management for your Organization, are you sure you've followed them all?

They are covered in detail in the [Enabling Territory Management](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_enable.htm&language=en_US) documentation and [Deploying Territory Management Guide](https://na19.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_territories_implementation_guide.pdf).

The key ones are as follows:

1. Enable Customizable Forecasting
2. Have a Sandbox
3. Contact salesforce.com to enable Territory Management for your Organization

Answer (score 1):

Territory management is changing as we speak for Salesforce. There were a number of difficulties with Territories version 1.

As of Summer 14, there is a new Beta feature of Territory Management 2.0. If you are strongly leaning toward this strategy, you could begin evaluating the use of this feature now by:

1. Reading the [release notes for Summer 14](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/summer14/release-notes/rn_sales_territory_management_2.htm).
2. Joining the success community Chatter group [Sales Cloud – Territory Management](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001qoq)
3. Reading the [docs Territory Management 2.0](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tm2_territory_mgmt_overview.htm&language=en_US) to see if it fits what you want